# java.lang.No classDefFound error while using PEXML for android in Libgx

Tags: libgdx

I am using PEXML library for giving physics to bodies in my game. It worked very well in desktop but when I ran in android it is giving me error at code 
`playerPhysics = new PEXML(Gdx.files.internal("data/physics.xml").file());`

and showing error

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBContext; at com.hi5dev.box2d_pexml.PEXML.loadXML(PEXML.java:124) at com.hi5dev.box2d_pexml.PEXML.(PEXML.java:24)
>     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.myplayer.football/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9...

Answer (score 1):

Google search shows `javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext` is in the file `javax.xml.bind.jar`

Java needs to find this file at runtime. It looks for it in your Java classpath ( set of directories ).

You need this Jar to be in your runtime classpath

The error you wrote about shows you the classpath.

You can either

1. put javax.xml.bind.jar in the current classpath
   ***or***
2. Modify the classpath to include the location of  javax.xml.bind.jar

Lookup how to modify the Java classpath for your operating system.